# Overriding Base Property and Accessing Reference in Base

Tags: c#, list, reference, overriding, radix

In the code below I have a property in base class which returns a list of custom objects. In the parent class I override this property and in the definition of the override I access the reference to the list of custom objects from the base class and add 2 objects to it.

Before returning I put a breakpoint in the code and check the content of the base property and notice that the two new objects are not there. Then I tried storing the reference to the list of objects in the base class locally and added two objects in the list again. I notice that in the local reference the 2 new objects have been added.

However, using both methods I'm pointing to the same reference so I should be able to add objects by referring to the base.TestProperty. Any idea why that won't work?

```
public override List<CustomObject> TestProperty  
{  
    get  
    {  
        List<CustomObject> temp = base.TestProperty;

        CustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject()
        {
            Name = "My Name"
        };

        CustomObject obj2 = new CustomObject()
        {
            Name = "Your Name"
        };

    // Adding to the base list
        base.TestProperty.Add(obj1);
        base.TestProperty.Add(obj2);

    // Adding to temp list, which still points to the base list
        temp.Add(obj1);
        temp.Add(obj2);

    // Base object doesnot contain obj1 and obj2, but the temp object does.
        return base.TestProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: implementation of base.TestProperty pls

Comment: Sounds like base.TestProperty returns `new List<CustomObject>()`.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to reproduce the issue you've described.

Comment: Ahh, It makes so much sense looking at the base.TestProperty implementation. It's building a new list every time and populating it with objects from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the specific answer you're looking for, but... you should really reconsider your design.

You've got a property in your subclass... and *getting* that property changes your class' values.  That's *extremely* counterintuitive.  It's not like you'd expect:

```
Color bgCol = Color.Red;
int red = bgCol.R;
```

... that second statement to *change values* of your variable just by accessing one of its properties!  How confused would you be if, when running that second statement, it changed the contents of bgCol to yellow?

My advice?  Have the base class return what it's supposed to - forgetting about the subclass.  And if your subclass needs to add values to that result?  Then have it add the values when the subclass's property is called - *but only to the result it's passing back* - don't have it mess with the base object's properties at all.

```
public override List<CustomObject> TestProperty  
{  
    get  
    {
        List<CustomObject> objectsFromBase = base.TestProperty;
        List<CustomObject> objectsFromThisClass = GetMySubclassCustomObjects();
        List<CustomObject> retVal = new List<CustomObject>();
        retVal.AddRange(objectsFromBase);
        retVal.AddRange(objectsFromSubclass);
        return retVal;
    }
}
private List<CustomObject> GetMySubclassCustomObjects()
{
    // your code for those two CustomObjects, and returning them from a list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but the statement that Ed Plunkett made is exactly the answer to my question. The base class was in a compiled binary so without looking at it's implementation I assumed it was using the same list every time.